# Function to Convert Decimal Time to Normal Time is Not Working Properly

Tags: python, time, rounding

I have the following Python functions to convert normal time into decimal time and vice versa:

```
import math

def std_to_dec(hour, minute, second):
    dec_total_seconds = (3600*hour+60*minute+second)/0.864
    dec_hour = int(str(dec_total_seconds/float(10000))[0])
    dec_minute = int(str(dec_total_seconds/float(10000))[2:4])
    dec_second = int(str(dec_total_seconds/float(10000))[4:6])
    return [dec_hour, dec_minute, dec_second]

def dec_to_std(hour, minute, second):
    std_total_seconds = (10000*hour+100*minute+second)*0.864
    std_hour = math.floor(std_total_seconds/float(3600))
    std_minute = math.floor((float(str(std_total_seconds/float(3600))[str(std_total_seconds/float(3600)).find('.'):]))*60)
    std_minute_dec = (float(str(std_total_seconds/float(3600))[str(std_total_seconds/float(3600)).find('.'):]))*60
    std_second = math.floor((float(str(std_minute_dec)[str(std_minute_dec).find('.'):]))*60)
    return [std_hour, std_minute, std_second]
```

When I do `print(std_to_dec(18, 21, 47))` I get `[7, 65, 12]`, which is all fine. But when I try to do it vice versa, `print(dec_to_std(7, 65, 12))`, I get `[18, 21, 46]`, which is not the same.

Additionally, `std_to_dec(0, 0, 0)` returns the error:

> dec_second = int(str(dec_total_seconds/float(10000))[4:6]) ValueError:
> invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

`dec_to_std(0, 0, 0)` works though.

Comment: Your function has more problems than that. Try calling `std_to_dec(0, 0, 0)`

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that. Not sure how to fix that either, so I'll add that to the question.

Comment: As soon as you divide or multiply by 0.864 you're in trouble

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: @pointySphere Multiplying or dividing by 0.864 will lead to rounding errors for some values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the string representation your code *expects* to have a string with at least 6 characters (which is not always the case) and ignores any characters from the 7th character onwards, losing precision, and leading to differences when converting back.

A core problem however is that standard time has 60*60*24 = 86400 possible times, while decimal time has 10*100*100 = 100000 (more) possible times. By consequence there is no 1-to-1 mapping possible, as then you would need an equal number of possibilities at both sides. However, as standard time has less possibilities, it must be possible to do that mapping as you require, but that means that some possibilities for decimal time will not occur.

Here is what you could use to always get the same standard time back when having it converted to decimal time and back:

```
def std_to_dec(hour, minute, second):
    dec = round((3600*hour+60*minute+second)/0.864)
    dec_second = dec % 100
    dec //= 100
    dec_minute = dec % 100
    dec //= 100
    dec_hour = dec
    return [dec_hour, dec_minute, dec_second]

def dec_to_std(hour, minute, second):
    std = round((10000*hour+100*minute+second)*0.864)
    std_second = std % 60
    std //= 60
    std_minute = std % 60
    std //= 60
    std_hour = std
    return [std_hour, std_minute, std_second]
```

With this solution it is not possible to expect the inverse: there are decimal times such that if you would convert them to standard time and back, they don't result in the same decimal time. Again, this is because there are more decimal times than standard times (when only using integers of course).

For instance:

```
std_to_dec(0, 0, 3) == [0, 0, 3]
std_to_dec(0, 0, 4) == [0, 0, 5]
```

This means that decimal time [0, 0, 4] will not occur, and also means that if you do the inverse, starting with that decimal time, you cannot get it back:

```
dec_to_std(0, 0, 4) == [0, 0, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Converting standard to decimal time (and *vice versa*) will result in rounding errors for some values.

In the original question, OP is converting to and from strings which is quite unnecessary. If we take the mathematical approach, the issue becomes clearer.

```
def std_to_dec(hh, mm, ss):
    seconds = int((((hh * 60) + mm) * 60 + ss) / 0.864)
    ds = seconds % 100
    seconds //= 100
    dm = seconds % 100
    return seconds // 100, dm, ds

def dec_to_std(hh, mm, ss):
    seconds = int((((hh * 100) + mm) * 100 + ss) * 0.864)
    ss = seconds % 60
    seconds //= 60
    sm = seconds % 60
    return seconds // 60, sm, ss

standard = 18, 21, 47
print('Standard time', standard)
sd = std_to_dec(*standard)
print('Decimal time', sd)
print('Recalculated', dec_to_std(*sd))
```

**Output:**

```
Standard time (18, 21, 47)
Decimal time (7, 65, 12)
Recalculated (18, 21, 46)
```

Comment: I seem to have replicated @trincot's answer but I'll leave it here anyway